# Preserve API key integrity with Travis-CI build-notification hooks in a public repository

Tags: encryption, continuous-integration, environment-variables, yaml, travis-ci

### The Context:

I've [open-sourced a repository](https://github.com/excellenteasy/grunt-pathfinder), which is tested by Travis-CI. Travis offers [build-notification](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/notifications/) hooks for the test runs, so you can get notified inside IRC, Flowdock, Campfire and HipChat. To configure these hooks you have to add settings to your `.travis.yml` config file, which is public. For Hipchat it looks like this:

```
notifications:
  hipchat: [api token]@[room name]
```

If I'd just put my token there in plain text everyone could see my API Token and access/spam my chatrooms. Among other things that's why Travis added [secure environemt variables](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Secure-environment-variables). Basically you can encrypt strings with your key and bind them specifically to the repository, so Travis can access the secret API keys.

What you do locally:

```
gem install travis
travis encrypt github-user/repo MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret
```

What you put into `.travis.yml`

```
secure: <encrypted string here>
```

### The Problem:

Unfortunately the documentation isn't overly verbose, google doesn't help, stackoverflow doesn't help **yet** and I can't get this to work.

[Here is my first try](https://github.com/excellenteasy/grunt-pathfinder/blob/28a75631ba89af2519b14bfc51dcf06377b38353/.travis.yml#L8):

`travis encrypt github-user/repo HIPCHAT=super_secret`

```
secure: <encrypted string here>
notifications:
  hipchat: <%= ENV['HIPCHAT'] %>@hipchat-room
```

As this doesn't work I went to travis irc on freenode and [that's what they suggested](https://github.com/excellenteasy/grunt-pathfinder/blob/a553ec2da2081a37dbc043e9d6dd08fb6acdbe8a/.travis.yml#L8)

`travis encrypt github-user/repo key@hipchat-room`

```
notifications:
  hipchat:
    secure: <encrypted string here>
```

As you might have guessed (why am I writing this question again?) this doesn't work either.
I hope you can help me fix this problem. Thank you very much

Edit: I'm very suspicious of myself. I tripple-checked the API key, it is working. It's up to Travis.

2Edit: As this appears to be a bug here is the corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-core/issues/157)

Comment: There is a fuller description of the setup process here: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#HipChat-notification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stephan,

Could you please try this:

```
notifications:
  hipchat:
    - secure: "encrypted string"
```

If you don't want to clutter up your commit history, you can push it on a separate branch and Travis should test that branch for you.

--Henrik

Comment: There was a bug with the way strings were decrypted, so none of the notification engines could access the decrypted strings. This has been fixed now.